# Equivalent of React.FC type, in Preact

Tags: reactjs, typescript, preact

The type of a functional React component is `React.FC`.
What would be the equivalent of this type  in `preact`?

Comment: Is this for the typescript typings? If so its just FunctionalComponent.

Comment: ‍♂️ That was it, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Typescript, the preact equivalent is `FunctionalComponent`.

[Github TS Definitions for preact.](https://github.com/preactjs/preact/blob/383443976e418033e448505aa6b4c53a07a65be4/src/index.d.ts#L80)